# WPF 4 Embeding Report Designer

Tags: wpf, reporting-services, report-designer

Is it possible to embed the Visual Studio 2010 report designer functionality into my WPF application?
Initially I was considering the use of Report builder, but for providing ad-hoc reporting capability from within application, I need to teach users too many steps before they start creating a simple report. So I am now thinking of simplifying it by embedding the report Designer (if it is possible), and do all the basic steps programatically and show the design surface and Data objects on the left.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if you can load an RDL/RDLC file into a WPF window?

Comment: No, I can Load an RDLC file using the reportViewer Control. I am looking for an option to display reportbuilder within the WPF window. There is no reportbuilder available in the toolbox, I could not even locate anywhere on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any good way so far and decided to use Report Builder instead. The approach I took is to build a report skeleton programtically with connection and query embedded in the RDL to expose object model instead of tables and views and launching the Report Builder to open this RDL. Yes.. there is lot of overhead that I need to build a query with lot of unnecessary fields and joins and the resulting performance is terrible. In a future version I will come up asking the users the fields they need to use int he report to improve performance.

Looks like Microsoft is going to make customers pay for SSRS from 2012 version. So this choice of use SSRS may even b ruled out.